# How many different groups of 3 can you create from a total of 20 people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm trying to wrap my head around an exercise in discrete math regarding combinatorics & permutations.

I have a group of 20 people and need to find how many unique groups of 3 I can create.

I've been reading up on other posts here but I've found several approaches to similar tasks and I'm not really sure which one is right for me so I decided to create a new post.

So far I think that the following solution is the most likely correct approach for me:

$\frac{20*19*18}{3*2*1}= 1140$

Hopefully this is the correct approach but I saw someone else introduce the binomial coefficient in the solution to a similar exercise and that made me wonder if I'm doing this right or not.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the right answer. I think the "binomial coefficient" that you are referring to might just be the choose function, or more specifically, $\binom{20}3$.

Comment: Ok, thank you that was good to hear.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  However, this is a [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) problem since you are selecting subsets.